# DE with separable method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the following differential equation:
$$y'=y^2+1, \ y(1)=0$$
My solution: We can solve it via separable method: $\dfrac{dy}{y^2+1}=dx$ and after integrating we get: $\arctan y=x+C \Rightarrow y=\tan (x+C)$ and taking into account initial condition we get $y=\tan(x+\pi k-1)$ where $k$ is an integer.

Indeed, if we put this function into our equation we get identity. However, the answer on the book is $y=\tan (x-1)$. Can anyone explain this discrepancy please?

Answer (score 1):

Well for $k=0$, your solution would equal to that in the book. The solution in the book is **a** solution, yours is more general and is also correct.

The $\pi k$ simply shifts the function left or right $\pi k$, and because tangent is a special function that repeats every $\pi$, $\pi k$ doesn't change the solution.

Comment: Thanks! Hope that I am correct.

Comment: @RFZ Remember to check an answer you deem satisfactory, or ask for more clarification to ensure that we can give you the best answer possible.

Answer (score 1):

The tangent function has period $\pi$, so $\tan(x-1+\pi k)=\tan(x-1)$ for all integers $k$.

Comment: Great! I have totally forgotten about that. Thanks a lot, dear Hans.